# Can I only write last 50 lines console output to a file automatically

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it possible to only write the last 50 lines of console output to a file automatically?

So that the file is always overwritten by the latest 50 lines.

Comment: You can use a pipe to tail. How is this question related to c++?

Answer (score 3):

You can use shell to modify and redirect the output of your program :

```
my_program | tail -n 50 > my_file
```

use simple redirection `>` if you want to truncate the file or double redirection `>>` if you want to append it.

**Note :**

This method only redirect stdout if you need to redirect stderr put `2>&1` after `my_program`

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this in C++, you could store your console output line by line in a container while your program is running and write the last 50 lines to your file when needed.

Write a wrapper for your output function and each time you print a line to the console, add it to a `std::queue`. If that makes your queue larger than 50 elements, pop the oldest one (just call `pop()`).

```
class Logger {
    static std::queue<string> lastFifty;

    public static void log(const std::string& str) {
        lastFifty.push(str);
        if (lastFifty.size() > 50) {
            lastFifty.pop();
        }
        std::cout << str;
    }

    public static void dumpToFile(std::ofstream& file) {
        while (!lastFifty.empty()) {
            file << lastFifty.pop();
        }
    }
}
```